# Should I migrate my data on my moto G7 power

Tags: internal-storage, data-transfer

I have a Motorola Moto G7 power. I just recently formatted my SD card to internal bc I needed the space but now my phone seems to be lagging bad and I see this migrate data thing but idk if I should do it or not. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I control where apps are installed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139688/can-i-control-where-apps-are-installed)